# Take control of Seaborn marginal histograms?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

Question 1:
How do I remove excess space in the plot, when plotting marginals? Answered below in first post.

Question 2:
How do I get more fine contorl over the margin histogram plots, e.g. to plot both histogram and decide kde parameters for the marginals? Answered below in second post, with `JointGrid`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sns.set_palette("viridis")
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(5, 1, 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x, "y":y})

g = sns.jointplot(df["x"],df["y"], bw=0.15, shade=True, xlim=(-3,3), ylim=(2,8),cmap="coolwarm", kind="kde", stat_func=None)

# plt.tight_layout() # This will override seaborn parameters. Remember to exclude.
plt.show()
```

Comment: Isn't [the `jointplot` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) already quite good? It has a list of all arguments, as well as many examples. Now if there is something specific you want to control, you would need to tell what it is, otherwise (except for the `space`) this is really too broad.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Seems to be more like a rubber duck question than anything someone can help you with. Unless you would decide to specify a problem. What does "restore" mean here? What is the desired output?

Comment: Alright, if this thread only serves to confuse, want me to close it?

Comment: No, just clearly state what the problem is. Besides you already got an answer. So at the limit you could edit the question such that @error 's answer matches.

Comment: Changed a bit. Is it more concise now?

Comment: Well, I guess it's ok, since both questions got answered somehow. Don't forget to accept one of them, such that the question will not stay open forever. Also, next time asking, ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 4):

`jointplot` has a `space` parameter that determines the space between the mainplot and the marginplots.

Running this code:

```
g = sns.jointplot(df["x"],df["y"], bw=0.15, shade=True, xlim=(-3,3), 
                  ylim=(2,8),cmap="coolwarm", kind="kde",
                  stat_func=None, space = 0)

plt.show()
```

results in this plot for me:

[image]

Please note that running with `plt.tight_layout()` will overrule the `space` argument for `jointplot`.

Edit:

To further specify the parameters of the marginal plot you can use `marginal_kws`. You must pass a dictionary that specifies the parameters of the kind of marginal plot you use.

In your example you use the `kde` plot as marginal plots. So I will continue to use that as an example:

Here I show how to change the kernel used to make the marginal plots.

```
g = sns.jointplot(df["x"],df["y"], bw=0.15, shade=True, xlim=(-3,3), 
                  ylim=(2,8),cmap="coolwarm", kind="kde",
                  stat_func=None, space = 0, marginal_kws={'kernel': 'epa'})


plt.show()
```

resulting in this graph:

[image]

You can pass any parameter accepted by the kde plot as a key in the dictionary and the desired value for that parameter as the value of for that key.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I'm going to go ahead and post an extra answer myself. It's not entirely apparent to me which parameters the extra `marginal_kws` can control. Instead, it might be more intuitive to build the plot layer-by-layer (especially coming from ggplot) using `JointGrid`:

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x="x", y="y", data=df)            # Initiate multi-plot
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot)                           # Plot the center x/y plot as sns.kdeplot
g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, kde=True)            # Plot the edges as sns.distplot (histogram), where kde can be set to True
```